# Formulario con select, hacer multiplicación de numero productos por el precio

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un formulario de pedidos donde, a través de un `select` se selecciona desde una base de datos el tipo de producto y necesito que, al seleccionarlo me añada el campo precio unitario para poderlo multiplicar con el resultado del numero de productos que el usuario inserta. Estoy tratando de aprender la dinámica, pienso que se debe usar el `input hidden` para llamar el dato del precio unitario, pero no se como integrarlo al `select`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

      <br>

    <form method='post' action='insertprueba.php' target='_self'>

      <div class="form-group" >

        <input type="hidden" name="preciobot" value="$preciobot">

        <select class="form-control" name="tipobot" id="tipobot" required="">    

          <option value="">Seleccionar el tamaño:</option>

          <?php  include 'conexion.php';

          mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8"); //*--conexion*//

          $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM  preciobot"); //*--variable llamadatos*//

          while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            echo '<option value="' . $valores[tambot] . '" , "' . $valores[preciobot] . '">' . $valores[tambot] . ' : ' . $valores[preciobot] . '</option>';  

          }

          ?>     

        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">

    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>

              <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control input-lg" name="cantibot" placeholder="Ingresar Cantidad Botellas" required>

            </div>

          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

        </form>

      </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Php:

```
<?php include 'conexion.php';    
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}
        $tipobot = $_POST['tipobot'];
        $cantibot = $_POST['cantibot'];
        $preciobot = $_POST['preciobot'];
        $costo_pedido = $_POST['costo_pedido']; 
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pedidos ( tipobot, cantibot, costo_pedido )
    VALUES ('" . $_POST["tipobot"] . "',
            '" . $_POST["cantibot"] . "',
            '" . $_POST["costo_pedido"] . "')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
header("Location: /pruebasuma/formprueba.php");
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar `JS` para realizar lo que requieres, puedes agregar otro atributo a tu `option`, en este ejemplo le puse precio, con `JS` obtengo el atributo del `option` que he seleccionado, una vez que lo obtengo lo `parseo` a un flotante con `parseFloat()` o si vas a manejar enteros usa `parseInt()`, después cuando paso al `input` de cuántas unidades quiero, igual el valor lo `parseo` y lo multiplico por el valor de precio y lo muestro en otro `input`, igual si necesitas mandar ese valor a un archivo `PHP` para insertar lo puedes hacer con `AJAX`, `JS` y `AJAX` te facilitan la vida, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
let precio;

$('#cantidad').attr('disabled', true);

$('#preciobot').change(function(){

if($(this).val() == ''){

$('#cantidad').attr('disabled', true);

$('#cantidad').val('');

$('#resultado').val('');

}else{

$('#cantidad').attr('disabled', false);

precio = $('#preciobot option:selected').attr('precio');

console.log(precio);

}



})

$('#cantidad').keyup(function(){

let valorInput = $('#cantidad').val();

let suma = parseFloat(valorInput) * parseFloat(precio);

console.log(suma);

$('#resultado').val(suma);

if($(this).val() == ''){

$('#resultado').val('');
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="preciobot" name="preciobot">
<option value="" precio="">Selecciona</option> 
<option value="Appleton" precio="150">Appleton</option>
<option value="Hornitos" precio="200">Hornitos</option>
<option value="Torres 10" precio="210">Torres 10</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="cantidad">

Resultado: <input type="text" id="resultado" readonly>
```

Comment: Vick Muñoz funcionó perfectamente, adapté el código para insertarlo en un db y listo, muchas gracias

Comment: Si se resolvio tu problema con mi respuesta, márcala como aceptada con palomita verde, así futuros compañeros si tienen el mismo problema sabrán cuál es la solución. :D