# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un formulario donde el usuario calcule cuánto cuesta una cantidad de productos iguales ingresando solo dicha cantidad?

Tags: css, javascript-objeto

El objetivo es ahorrarle al usuario la multiplicación de cantidades por precios. En el formulario es  mejor que no se vea el precio para simplificarlo. El precio será subido actualizado  periódicamente.
Parece simple pero no pude desarrollarlo. Traté de utilizar lo propuesto en  [Formulario con select, hacer multiplicación de numero productos por el precio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/268614/formulario-con-select-hacer-multiplicaci%C3%B3n-de-numero-productos-por-el-precio) pero incluye una elección entre varios productos que no es este caso.

Comment: Hola Ismael. Por lo que cuentas, estaría bien que utilizases javascript. Parece que es más una pregunta relacionada con ese lenguaje que con css. Un saludo y bienvenido

Comment: Hola Ismael, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!

Answer (score 1):

Yo también usaría `js`, te dejo un ejemplo para que te ayudes y te des una idea, recuerda que no es la única forma, en programación todos los caminos llevan a Roma.

```js
    function calcularPrecio() {
      // Obtener los valores del formulario
      var cantidad = parseInt(document.getElementById('cantidad').value);
      var precio = parseFloat(document.getElementById('precio').value);

      // Calcular el precio total
      var precioTotal = cantidad * precio;

      // Mostrar el resultado
      document.getElementById('precioTotal').textContent = precioTotal.toFixed(2);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calculadora de Precio</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Calculadora de Precio</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
    <input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" required>
    <br><br>
    <label for="precio">Precio:</label>
    <input type="number" id="precio" name="precio" step="0.01" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcularPrecio()">
  </form>
  <br>
  <h2>Precio Total: $<span id="precioTotal"></span></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero te sugiero que evites responder preguntas que tengan un formato pobre o no adecuado al sitio. Te sugiero leer [answer] y [ask]. La pregunta podría terminar cerrada y tu aporte se pierde. Saludos

Comment: Hola Kenneth, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, más allá de lo que te indica Mauricio, poner un script dentro de la cabecera no es una buena práctica, por otro lado, en esta página, puedes usar **snippet's**, que en html, css y js, te permiten ejecutar el código, intenta editar tu respuesta y verás como los apliqué.

Comment: Listo, disculpe, gracias por la información y la aclaración, lo pondré en desarrollo para futuras respuestas y preguntas, Pura vida!